# catching error on successful api post - Axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

My saga posts file attachment to the api successfully, but its still catching an error, telling the user the attachement didnt upload. My console log also shows the catch.

Here is my code... anything obviously wrong here?

```
const postFileUpload = async (payload) => {
    let data = {};

    var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token; // Here gapi is used for retrieving the access token.

    try {
        const { id, campDate, type, file } = payload;

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('type', type);
        if (campDate !== undefined) {
            formData.append('campDate', campDate);
        }
        formData.append('id', Id);

        const response = await axios.post(
            `https://${API_ENDPOINT}/attachments`,
            formData,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
                }
            }
        );
        console.log('SUCCESS!!');
        if (!response.success) {
            throw new Error(response.erorrMessage);
        }
        data = response.data;
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('FAILURE!!', error);
        console.error('Error uploading attachment');
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: can You print the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the response from the post-call has a `.success` attribute?

I would check on the status code instead.

Comment: I needed to look at response.data.success

Comment: Awesome! :)  Glad to help you out!